# internationalization single page site

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization

I want to provide different translations on a single page website. Is it a good idea to translate every text entry using this approach (pseudo code):

html

```
<p id="my_text"></p>
```

js (jQuery)

```
function init(){
    $('#my_text')[0].innerHTML(isEnglish ? "Hello" : "Hallo");
}
```

If this solution has any disadvantages or will lead to issues, please let me know which (simple) solution is the better option.

Comment: there are a lot of libraries for internationalization , ex polyglot js http://airbnb.io/polyglot.js/polyglot.html

Comment: @VladuIonut looks nice, thanks!

Comment: you might read https://medium.com/@jamuhl/i18n-frameworks-the-unfair-showdown-8d436cd6f470 to get an overview for i18n frameworks out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, this is going to be tedious for a long passage.
I would suggest you use a [bing translation API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990932/translating-complete-web-page-with-bing-tranlation-api)